# Getting Django server to subscribe to another Django server with Channels WebSockets

Tags: django, django-channels

I am trying to work out how I can get **Django Server B(IOT device)** to subscribe to **Django Server A (cloud)** using **Channels WebSockets**.

This is so that I can pass data async between them. Server B will be on an IOT device and Server A will be cloud-based. I've been looking everywhere, but most of the online tutorials and documentation seems to be based on subscribing(client-side) with Javascript. Surely there must be a way to subscribe with Python! Most of the online tutorials seem to be for chat apps too. It would be great if someone could help please. I'm sure there are other people looking for this same answer too. Thank you :)

Comment: This package may be useful for you https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Comment: Thank you Iain, I will try this out. Much appreciated!